# javascript sign in and sign up proplem

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, local-storage, account

i need to get this working with front-end i want to make client add his data and be saved to be used in signing in and i can't sign in without signing up but i just make it see if the saved data are equal the entered value or not but i can't make more than one account any solutions?

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="first">
        <h1>make an account</h1>
        <form onsubmit="return false">
            new Name:<input id='nus' type="text" placeholder="Type your name here">
            new password:<input id='npass' type="password" placeholder="Type your password here">
            <button onclick="addaccount()" type="submit">add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="scnd" style="display: none;">
        <p id='txt'></p>
        <form onsubmit="return false">
            Name:<input id='bar' type="text" placeholder="Type your name here">
            password:<input id='pass' type="password" placeholder="Type your password here">
            <button onclick="insert()" type="submit" id='insbtn'>insert</button>
        </form>
        <h1 id="acc" style="display: none;"> example for text <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
            adipisicing elit. Magni ipsum voluptatibus quis eos laudantium commodi quae pariatur magnam in rem
            odio,
            neque officia tempora repellat ea soluta atque eius expedita!</h1>
    </div>
    <script>

        function addaccount() {
            var first = document.getElementById('first')
            const nus = document.getElementById('nus').value;
            const npass = document.getElementById('npass').value;
            localStorage.setItem('nus', nus)
            localStorage.setItem('npass', npass)
            first.style.display = 'none'
            scnd.style.display = 'block'
        }
        function insert() {

            var scnd = document.getElementById('scnd')
            var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
            var bar = document.getElementById('bar').value;
            var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
            var insbtn = document.getElementById('insbtn');
            var acc = document.getElementById('acc')
            localStorage.setItem('name', bar);
            localStorage.setItem('password', pass);

            var getus = localStorage.getItem('name')
            var getpass = localStorage.getItem('password');
            /*tried to set the username and password myself but i found it silly now i can't make more than a 
            user login and i can't go directly to signing in*/
            if (localStorage.getItem('nus') == bar && localStorage.getItem('npass') === pass) {
                acc.style.display = 'block';
                txt.innerHTML = 'hello' + ' ' + getus
            }
            else {
                txt.innerHTML = 'error not your account'
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have two `<form>` elements, and the first one is not closed?

Comment: Also, using `localStorage` as a medium for user account storage is.....odd.

Comment: what can be other alternatives?

Comment: Anything involving a server that is a shared resource to multiple users.  That's a very broad question.

Comment: so using back-end would be better?

Comment: With regards to it being available to multiple users, and for security concerns, infinitely better.

Comment: what is prefered to be used for back-end node or PHP or something else

Comment: It depends entirely on what you have available, and what you are knowledgable with.  Both will work.

Comment: i know javascript so i think node would be easier to learn thanks for help